# Spring Data, MongoTemplate save() and REST

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, mongotemplate

I develop a `REST API` and use Spring Data `MongoTemplate` for saving any resources on `Mongo` Database.

One of API is :

`PUT /devices/{deviceId}`

For REST compliant, I should return `200` for an `update` or `201` for `create`.

When I do a `MongoTemplate.save(device)`, how can I know if mongo do `insert()` or `update()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, before you save your object into a `MongoDB`, check whether its `ID` is `null`. If `null`, you are doing insertion, if not `null`, you are doing an update.

Comment: Hi, in my case, my object ID is never null because it's a functional ID and it's mapped on "_id" with a Converter<DBObject, Device>. Other solutions ?